# Is Beacon Node Consensus Client Lighthouse a buggy? Unreasonable for anyone to get CheckPointSyncURL who just start and decide to install full node

Tags: go-ethereum, consensus, full-node, lighthouse, beacon

I have tried to sync full Ethereum node for 3+ weeks.
Tried with 4 VPS servers and when I am gonna sync lighthouse and Geth simulatenously,
it was working well. But after a few hours, lighthouse syncing speed decrease every hour.
At first 150slots/s , 80 slots/s, .... , now 6.66 slots/s and it is said that

```
[Warn] BlockProcessingFailure    Outcome: MissingBeaconBlock (....), Msg: Unexpected condition in processing Block...
```

And I did restart the sync and now it says

```
CRIT Failed to start beacon node Failed to build beacon chain: Head block not found in store
```

After a few hours of research, I could know that I need to re-sync from scratch by purge-db. And the reason might be database corrupt because of Hard drive which is really unreasonable in my case.
My resource is NVME SSD 1TB, 64GB RAM, 8 CORE CPU, 2TB Bandwidth, 2GB+/s download/upload internet speed that is very new physical bare mental server.

What I want to understand is that I have installed the latest lighthouse version and use the computer that I think more than enough to sync full node, but it happens not only first time for me.

It happens 3rd time for me that I have failed about this. (Just one time every VPS.)
I waited more than 5 days still now and just started syncing with GETH (1 day passed - not sure how long this would take - maybe need to wait 5+ days more), but this is very unreasonable not only for me, but for everyone who spends most of the computer resources which are very valuable and failed at the very last moment.

Sometimes they say that it will be very fast to sync from check-point-sync url, but after a few days and lots of hours I spent for the research, I could know that there is no way to find the correct url. Because check-point-sync url means I get another one's full node url. It is impossible for any general person because having full ethereum node url means that you already have it or you can use it. Why do you spend efforts to sync full node? Also, how can you find node url? All of the checkpoint sync urls on the internet (that are free) are free and fake ones, even if you can connect there, its sync speed will be very slower than syncing from your own.

Is there anyone who can help me? Or fix this? Just want to have a best solution for now. I really don't want to re-sync from scratch and also I am really not sure if this kind of thing could happen again even if I resync again.  If there is no way without re-sync from scratch, I will absolutely choose another consensus client. Anyone please recommend me about this.
It will take 1+ year if things are like this. Thanks.